# MySQL and MongoDB used on grails webapp together.

Tags: mysql, mongodb, grails-domain-class

I have a User domain class that contains Profile domain class for the user. I need to use MongoDB for the Profile domain class in order to perform certain document search queries. Currently I have an instance of Profile in the User domain class as User has Profile, or Profile belongs to User.

I was wondering if such approach is going to cause problem down the road. Meaning that I have two domain classes which are pulling data from two different data sources.

Comment: There's not a general answer to this question that would be a good fit for StackOverflow. Do you have specific concerns that you could ask about?

Comment: I want to know if this approach is wrong. I couldn't find any article or discussion online that discuss such approach. I did a light test and it worked but I'm not sure if there is some caveat on this.